# Fixing DISTINCT in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Hi I am trying to fill gridview from datatable and to make distinct of the rows and I have achived this result:

[image]

this is the code that I use after fillin gridview:

```
int k = 0;
        for (int i = myGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            GridViewRow row = myGridView.Rows[i];
            GridViewRow previousRow = myGridView.Rows[i - 1];

            for (int j = 0; j < row.Cells.Count; j++)
            {
                if ((row.Cells[k].Text == previousRow.Cells[k].Text) && (row.Cells[j].Text == previousRow.Cells[j].Text))
                {
                    if (previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                        {
                            previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan += 2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan = row.Cells[j].RowSpan + 1;
                        }
                        row.Cells[j].Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But as you can see this is very good only for the first 3 columns and after that it doesnt work.

The result that I need is this:

[image]

I tried all the above

Comment: Distinct uses a custom IEqualityComparer<T>.  So create a IEqualityComparer<T> class to get the rows that match using only the columns you want to use.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-7.0